# How to count the number of different letter between a string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I was trying to find the difference in letters between two strings.
For example, if I put the word ATTGCC and GTTGAC, the difference would be 2 since A and G and C and G are not the same characters.

```
class DNA
  def initialize (nucleotide)
    @nucleotide = nucleotide
  end
  def length
    @nucleotide.length
  end
  def hamming_distance(other)
    self.nucleotide.chars.zip(other.nucleotide) { |a,b| a == b }.count
  end

  protected

  attr_reader :nucleotide
end

dna1 = DNA.new("ATTGCC")
dna2 = DNA.new("GTTGAC")


puts dna1.hamming_distance(dna2)
```

The method hamming_distance doesn't really work as it gives a wrong argument type String (must respond to :each) (TypeError)

Comment: lookup https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Comment: Given your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39711526/how-to-compare-two-instance-variables-from-the-same-class-in-ruby) I'm assuming the input strings are (for example) `"ATTGCC"` and `"GTTGAC"` and that the lengths will be equal. It's worth making these conditions explicit in your question.

Comment: Yeah, I went ahead and updated the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the strings are of the same length, you can split them, zip them, and find how many pairs match:

```
string1 = "RATTY"
string2 = "CATTI"

string1.chars.zip(string2.chars).select { |a,b| a == b }.count
```

- The `.chars` produces an array of the characters in the string (`"RATTY"` => `["R", "A", "T", "T", "Y"]`)
- The `.zip` call merges the two arrays together into a an array of pairs, `["R", "A", "T"].zip(["C", "A", "T"])` => `[ ["R", "C"], ["A", "A"], ["T", "T"]]`
- The `select` filters out the pairs where the values aren't equal
- The count returns the number of pairs matched by select

You can find the number of non-matching pairs by negating the selection

Comment: I'm sorry I guess I didn't explain the conditions of the program as that method is giving me a wrong argument type String (must respond to :each) (TypeError)

Comment: string1.chars.zip(string2.chars).count { |a,b| a == b } will give same result.